# Why is :hover selector of svg not working when placed inside a div

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg placed inside a div. on hovering, div is getting hovered but not the svg.

```
<div id="svgDiv" style="position: relative;"><svg class="svgIcons" style=""><use xlink:href="id from .svg file"></use></svg></div>

added css not working

.svgIcons:hover{
  fill: #fff;
}

but the following is working
#svgDiv:hover .svgIcons{
  fill:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Could you put a working example in your question with an actual SVG that shows the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem might be that your svg is on a lower z-index than your div causing the div to be on top. Try changing the `z-index` of your svg to a high value.

Comment: I still don't really understand why you don't use the working version you have. What's the reason for that?

Comment: I am trying to generalize but with the problem i have to add css class separately for each div required